# How to upload a database that's larger than 50MB in Live Server?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, cpanel

I want to upload MySQL database *systm_db.sql* which was extracted from localhost and it's of size 72MB.

Now, I want to upload it on remote server by using it's cPanel. Is there any way to modifiy cPanel's configuration like following:

```
memory_limit =750M
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time = 3000
max_input_time = 3000
```

*I successfully implemented & uploaded my database on localhost using above configuration, but I am unable to do like this.*

Comment: It is in your [`php.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.php). After updating your `php.ini`, restart your XAMPP control panel.

Comment: @LoganWayne I already did in case of localhost using XAMPP, but I need to do it using cPanel in live server. There is no xampp in real server.

Comment: https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403864/export-and-import-mysql-databases

Comment: If you like modify WHM/Cpanel server php.ini it's on /usr/local/lib/php.ini. Modify values, and after restart httpd with service httpd restart. Also can login to WHM, and on search box on left top put "PHP". You see adn link for Editing config of PHP. User Edit on Advanced mode. Edit your values. On this way not need restart Apache (WHM restart for you)

Comment: @abkrim I'm not seeing any additional link after searching "PHP" in WHM. I am try to contact Upper level reseller. Once again thank you, I'll answer this question if I succed.

Comment: Opps, if you not root (only reseller) You can't acces to this functions. In this case, others replies such long answer are correct for you (a IMHO it's best practise use mysql shell commands).

Answer (score -1):

you can zip file .sql before upload to server. we excecute zip file. :D

Comment: Not assk for alternatives methods.

Answer (score -1):

The following code snippets will allow you to import and export a large database using SSH commands.

To get SSH access to your hosts server you will need to contact your current `web hosting company.` If you are on a shared hosting package you may not be allowed to have SSH access to your hosts server.

To run both of these commands you will need to have MySQL installed on your server.

**Export Database**

To export the database you need to run the following command.

```
mysqldump -p -u username -h hostname database_name > dbname.sql
```

This runs the mysqldump command with a number of parameters. The first parameter is -p which means password, when you run this command the script will ask you to enter your database password. If you want to do this in one line then you type in the password after the -p without any spaces.

```
mysqldump -pP@55w0rd -u username -h hostname database_name > dbname.sql
```

The next parameter is -u which means `username`, this will be the `username` you use to access your database. The next parameter is -h for host, you only need to use this if your database is on a different server, if you have your database on the current server then you do not need this parameter.

Next you type in the database name that you want to export, followed by a > for export and then the name and location of the file you are going to export this data into. In this example it just puts the file in `dbname.sql` which will place the file in the current location you are in, if you want to put these in a certain folder you need to provide the full folder path.

**Import A Database**

With the SQL file that you have just exported you can now easily import this into any database that you want by using the following code snippet.

First you need to make sure that they file you want to import is of a .sql format, then upload this file to your server so that you have access to it from an SSH command. Next make sure that the database you want to import this file into has been created, now you will able to import the database.

```
 mysql -p -u username -h hostname database_name < /var/www/vhosts/website/backup/dbname.sql
```

This time you are running the mysql command with the same parameters, -p for password again if you want to put the password in this one command you can do or you will be asked for the password when you run this command. Next parameter is -u for the username of the database, -h for the host if the database is on a different server, next is the name of the database you want to import the SQL file. The next parameter is a < for import and then the location of the file you want to import.

Comment: Goog tutorial but question it's other. Question is about Cpanel, and php config.

Comment: The qestion asked by user it's not your answer. Its a greateful tutorial, but not a response for users question. Can help on futire? Sure. But there +1000 tutorials same and +1000 answers on Stack with same style. The question is not the future, it is the question of the user. Best regards