# Set a limit above 50MB on pgAdmin to upload a database backup to the server with Docker Compose

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

As written in the title I would like to set a limit higher than 50MB on pgAdmin to upload a backup of a database on the server with Docker Compose.

I have postgresql as database and pgadmin as program for managing that database. When I access pgadmin and I upload a file larger than 50MB the program blocks me. To solve it I have to change the default settings of pgadmin and increase the limit to 100MB, for safety and not to think about it I write 5000MB. I would like to change the pgadmin value of 50 to 5000 using docker compose and not the pgadmin control panel.

I looked at the following links but couldn't find anything:

https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4

https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/container_deployment.html

https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/container_deployment.html

https://www.pgadmin.org/support/list/

https://stackoverflow.com

I can do this manually but I would like to do it when I upload my project to the server with Docker.
This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM dpage/pgadmin4:6.18
LABEL Author="My name and my surname"
# ??? New limit ???
```

This is my docker compose .yaml file:

```
  pgadmin:
    build: ./pgadmin
    ...
    networks:
      ...
    labels:
      ...
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./volumes/data-pgadmin/servers.json
        target: /pgadmin4/servers.json
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ...
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ...
      # ??? New limit ???
    depends_on:
      - postgresql-postgis
```

Can you help me?
thank you

Comment: 1) `50MB` limit on what? 2) `pgAdmin4` is a client not the server so it has nothing to do with loading the backup to the server.

Comment: 1) 50MB is the maximum size of the file containing all the database data that can be uploaded to pgAdmin. 2) I'm referring to the pgAdmin limit, not the server.

Comment: I think this is what I need but the program mentioned in the thread is not pgadmin. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499713/how-to-upload-a-database-thats-larger-than-50mb-in-live-server

Comment: What’s wrong with pg_restore or psql? None of these have a memory limit

Comment: 1) That question has to do with `MySQL` and `cPanel` so it in no way  relates to your issue. 2) you don't upload data to `pgAdmin4` it is uploaded to the Postgres server. 3) You need to add to your question a more detailed explanation of where you are getting the data and what you want to upload it into.

Comment: It seems you don't understand my question. I have postgresql as database and pgadmin as program for managing that database. When I access pgadmin and I upload a file larger than 50MB the program blocks me. To solve it I have to change the default settings of pgadmin and increase the limit to 100MB, for safety and not to think about it I write 5000MB. I would like to change the pgadmin value of 50 to 5000 using docker compose and not the pgadmin control panel. Is the question clearer?

Comment: The question is clearer, so you should add the comment content to the question text itself. As to how to do that I don't know. I suspect it will involve modifying a configuration file. I have no idea what that file would be.

Comment: I added clarification to the question.

Comment: Since no one on this forum is able to give an answer where can I ask? In which forum do you recommend I ask for assistance? thank you

Answer (score 1):

in docker version of pgAdmin 7.6, you can do

File -> Preferences -> Storage -> Options

there is "Maximum file upload size". changed it to 1000 MB and storage manager allowed me to upload 700 MB file, so i guess it works.